# Does Mongoose support a choice of schemas for a property?

Tags: mongoose, schema

Is it possible to have a Schema with a property that must contain one of a number of sub document schemas?

```
var childSchema1 = new Schema({ name: 'string' });
var childSchema2 = new Schema({ age: 'number' });

var parentSchema = new Schema({
  // i.e child must be either childSchema1 or childSchema2
  child: [childSchema1, childSchema2]
})
```